# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array would exceed the maximum number of dimension of 2

Tags: python, numpy

Программа должна разделить элементы каждого столбца на его сумму. Затем сложить элементы строки и разделить на их кол-во.
В онлайн компиляторе она работает, но в PyCharm выдаёт вышеуказанную ошибку. Жалуется на A[:,i] не понимаю в чём проблема.

`````
A = np.matrix([[1,5,6,7],[1/5,1,4,6],[1/6,1/4,1,4],[1/7,1/6,1/4,1]])
print(np.around(A,decimals = 3,))
b=[0,0,0,0]
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    column = A[:,i]
    s = sum(column)
    print()
    column = [divide / s for divide in column]
    A[:,i] = column #ошибка здесь
print('Нормализованные столбцы:\n', np.around(A,decimals = 2,))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        b[i]+=A[i,j]/4
print('Сумма элементов строк: ',np.around(b,decimals = 3,))````
`````

Comment: Что тогда использовать? Да и данный фрагмент в коде 2 раза встречается, но ругается только на второй раз.

Comment: Отделить элемент строки от элемента столбца

Comment: А запятая то тут для чего? Где вы такую запись увидели?

Comment: У других в коде увидел :)

Comment: Ругается, потому что с размерностями проблемы. А вообще-то вы совсем не пользуетесь возможностями, которые дает numpy

Comment: @Павел запятая - это отлично в данном случае. это не обычный список списков, а numpy

Comment: @splash58 в первый раз сталкиваюсь, спасибо, что объяснили

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy позволяет делать вычисления по матрице без явных циклов, в чем собственно, одно из основных достоинств библиотеки

```
A = np.matrix([[1,5,6,7],[1/5,1,4,6],[1/6,1/4,1,4],[1/7,1/6,1/4,1]])
```

Программа должна разделить элементы каждого столбца на его сумму.

```
A = A / A.sum(axis=0)
```

Затем сложить элементы строки и разделить на их кол-во.

```
print(A.sum(axis=1) / A.shape[1])
```

---

Ваш код ругается, потому что с размерностями проблемы. чтобы он заработал, вычисляйте новую колонку так

```
column = column / s
```

если я чего не пропустил, в остальном он рабочий